# How to implement WhatsApp like image click functionality

Tags: android

I want to implement a functionality when I click a small ImageView, the Image should be shown in full screen with custom layout like imageview in whatsApp chat that gets open in full screen when user touch the imageview in chat.
And when I click back arrow button(in custom layout), I should go to previous small image view , **exactly like WhatsApp chat ImageView with animation also.I do not want to implement this full view in new Activity.
Is there any way for it?**

Comment: You can check github sample for this.Here is the one. https://github.com/egbakou/WhatsAppUI

Comment: Thanks Sam, but still it doesn't fit in my requirement.